# Updating attributes on multiple objects at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to update an attribute on multiple objects?
I'm trying to update my user's wins and losses every time their team's wins and losses gets updated.

I have three models linked together.

Players belong to teams. I'm trying to make it so that when a user joins a team, it creates a player with their name and role.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
end
```

Teams have many players. Teams hold name:string wins:integer losses:integer.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Users have many teams through players. So users are the players of the teams they join. When creating a new player the user links their name to the players. Users hold name:string email:string wins:integer losses:integer

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :teams, through: :players
end
```

So at this point I want to make is so when I update a teams wins and losses the player also gets updated with those wins and losses. How may I tackle this? I've tried to load all the team's users in an instance variable but it has more than one player and I can't update the wins from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rest of you application but based on your question I would suggest making another model `Matches`. You can connect it to `Team` via `has_many`. Then you can simply add a won/lost matches to the teams and set up your models so that you can create a query like

The models should look like this. You can set them up better if you want multiple teams to play the same match and save the result without duplicates (match could have multiple foreign keys, like `team1_id`, `team2_id`). Or if you want to also have drawn matches, save scores etc. For what you are asking I simply included one attribute `won`:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matches  
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team

  def self.won
    where(won: true)
  end

  def self.lost
    where(won: false)
  end
end
```

Now this query should work:

```
team.matches.won.count
```

Adding a match to a team should be simple:

```
team.matches.create(won: true)
```

Comment: how would I add a won/lost matches to the teams?

Comment: @linogomez I added more info to my answer